# How to print the index of the songs as well as their names?

Tags: python

I am building an AI assistant and I want to add an option to it that it could play the music that I choose by name and it only plays that specific song.

```
import os
music_dir = "C:\\Users\\Mahdi\\Downloads\\Music"
songs = os.listdir(music_dir)
input1 = input("Enter the song name: ")
print (songs)
song = os.startfile(os.path.join(music_dir, songs[1]))
```

Based on a helpful comment, I have now changed the code to:

```
import os
music_dir = "C:\\Users\\Mahdi\\Downloads\\Music"
songs = os.listdir(music_dir)
for i in range(len(songs)):
    print (songs[i])
input1 = int(input("Enter the song index: "))
song = os.startfile(os.path.join(music_dir, songs[input1]))
```

and when I run it, it shows me a list of song **names** and asks which song I want to play by its **index**.
Is there any way to print the indices too? So, for example when I run it it shows:

```
0 song name1
1 song name2
...
```

Comment: You're only choosing the second song in that directory. (You indexed by 1). You should just put `input1` instead of `songs[1]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can print both the index value and the song name using the built-in [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) function like this:

```
for i, song_name in enumerate(songs):
    print(i, song_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to the snippet below and it should all work fine.

```
import os
import sys, subprocess
print(sys.platform)
music_dir = "C:\\Users\\Mahdi\\Downloads\\Music"  
songs = os.listdir(music_dir)
print (songs)
input1 = input("Enter the song name: ")  
opener = "open" if sys.platform == "darwin" else "xdg-open"
subprocess.call([opener, os.path.join(music_dir, input1)])
```

`os.startfile()` does not work with Linux or Mac and works only on windows.